# (XSLT) How to recursively iterate through the same list for each item in the list?

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I'm a fairly strong OOP programmer, so I'm having a little trouble figuring out how XSLT "thinks" as a functional language.

The actual data I'm working with is sensitive, so instead let's suppose I have an XML list of `<albums>` that contain an `<artist>`, `<songs>` and each song may or may not have a `<guest_artist>`.

Roughly something like this:

```
<album>
    <album_name>First One</album_name>
    <artist_name>SomeGuy</artist_name>
    <song>
        <song_name>Somebody</song_name>
        <guest_artist>SomebodyElse</guest_artist>
    </song>
    ...
</album>
```

My goal is to produce a CSV text file of all the `<guest_artist>` that are also the primary artist on some other `<album>`, and the album in which they appear as a guest.

The output should look something like this:

```
Guest Artist Name,Album on which they were a Guest
SombodyElse,First One
```

My initial approach was to `<for-each>` over each `/album/guest_artist`. Firstly, store the guest artist's name, and then inside that loop, `<for-each>` again over each `../album/artist_name` and see if the stored variable matches any of the artist names. Within the inner loop, if there was a match, I write out a line.

Roughly like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Header Row Begins -->
    <xsl:textGuest Artist Name,Album on which they were a Guest</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

    <!-- Data Row Begins -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/album/song/guest_artist">
        <xsl:variable name="guest_name" select="guest_artist"/>
        <xsl:variable name="this_album_name" select="../album_name"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../album">
            <xsl:if test="$guest_name=artist_name">
                <xsl:value-of select="album/song/guest_artist"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$this_album_name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- Data Row End -->
</xsl:template>
```

(I'm not concerned about duplicates, yet. If I can figure the basics out, then I can solve that problem myself.)

This produces strange results. It seems to be listing all the guest artists first, then a comma, then all the album names, then a linefeed.

I'm not asking for the code (pseudo-code, perhaps). Rather, I just don't understand the features of XSLT that I need to look into, in order make this happen. It seems like for-each loops aren't behaving the way I expect them to. It's also not clear how scope is handled. I suspect that `<templates>` will be useful, but I'm having a hard time figuring out what they do, and how.

I've been through the W3 School course, and a few other tutorials on XSL, but they don't seem to cover these specifics.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be a lot simpler than I expected. The main problem is the "context" of each loop. The first `<for-each>` is evaluating one node, but then the second, nested `<for-each>` begins evaluating another node. Consequently, I have to be able to tell the inner `<for-each>` which node is being evaluated by the outer `<for-each>`. That's as simple as saving it in a variable. (Yes, in other places this is called "scope," but I'm not certain "scope" is the right term in this context).

It came out roughly like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="linefeed" select="'&#xA;'"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Header Row Begins -->
    <xsl:textGuest Artist Name,Album on which they were a Guest</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>

    <!-- Data Row Begins -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/album/guest_artist">
--->    <xsl:variable name="current_node" select="current()"/>
        <xsl:variable name="guest_name" select="guest_artist"/>
        <xsl:variable name="this_album_name" select="../album_name"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="../../album">
            <xsl:if test="$guest_name=artist_name">
--->            <xsl:value-of select="$current_node/guest_artist"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
--->            <xsl:value-of select="$current_node/../../album_name"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$linefeed"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- Data Row End -->
</xsl:template>
```

My paths might be off for this example. The translation from real data to example scenario isn't 100%, especially when I'm still new to XSL. But, the production version works ;-)

Comment: This code is looking very procedural in appearance. Most experienced XSLT users would be using template rules rather than for-each loops here. And the `xsl:if` directly within `xsl:for-each` should really be a predicate: `<xsl:for-each select="../../album[$guest_name = artist_name]"`.

Comment: Incidentally, I used the term "for-each loops" here, which Martin criticizes in his deleted answer. He's right: "loop" is loose talk. Correctly, it's a functional mapping operator that maps an input sequence to an output sequence. The key difference is that the order of evaluation of a "loop" is defined, whereas a mapping operator can process the items in the input sequence in any order, or in parallel.

Comment: That's helpful information. One of the problems I'm trying to solve is processing a massive amount of data more quickly. It's likely that a more experienced XSL user would already know that this approach is fundamentally hamstrung.